# how to add label to hangman game

Tags: java, user-interface

these are my code I've problem with label when i read line from the text filed i can add the labels "_" that they are equal to the size of the word the program road it before.
I've problem creating label , I hope you understand my problem & please if you can can you give me a solution ?

```
 public class HangGame extends JFrame {

     JLabel lbl;
    JLabel word ;
    private  String[]myword = new String [20];
   Game() {

}
    void readfile () {
Properties prob = new Properties();

try{

    for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
    }
    }}
    private void initLabelPanel() {
    //craete array of labels the size of the word
        letterHolderPanel = new JPanel();
        int count =0;
```

//if you run my code I've problem with this array [myword.length()] the compiler can not find it.

```
wordToFindLabels = new JLabel[myword.length()];
    //Initiate each labels text         add tp array and to letter holder panel
    for (int i = 0; ih; i++) {JLabel lbl = new JLabel("_");

    letterHolderPanel.add(lbl);
    lbl.setBounds();
    }
    }


}
```

Comment: what is exception while compiling?

Comment: please include the `import` statements from the top of your class in your example

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
 
        Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]

 at HangGame.initLabelPanel(HangGame.java:65)

 at HangGame.<init>(HangGame.java:29)

 at HangGame.main(HangGame.java:142)

Comment: I have all import statements sorry i forget to copy them

Answer (score 2):

`myword` is an array of `Strings`, not a single `String` so you need to replace:

```
wordToFindLabels = new JLabel[myword.length()];
```

with

```
wordToFindLabels = new JLabel[myword.length];
```

You could rename the variable to, say, `mywordArray`, to avoid confusion.

Also use a layout manager rather than using absolute positioning(null layout).

See: [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

Comment: I replaced this wordToFindLabels = new JLabel[myword.length];
I don't have any problem but labels doesn't add to my program still I try another way

Comment: you are better than me in programing can you give me another way for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

length is property not method change the code accordingly

```
wordToFindLabels = new JLabel[myword.length];
```

and now youre code will be

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordToFindLabels.length; i++) {
String labelValue="";
if(myword[i] != null) {
for (int j = 0; j < myword[i].length(); j++){
  labelValue+="_"
}
}
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(labelValue);
    wordToFindLabels[i] = lbl;

    letterHolderPanel.add(lbl);
    lbl.setBounds(30, 60, 20, 20);
    }
```

Comment: I replaced this wordToFindLabels = new JLabel[myword.length]; I don't have any problem but labels doesn't add to my program

Comment: can you give me another solution ?

Comment: Can you explain the problem? do you only want _(underscore) or words with under score? or underscore should be equal to number of words? or equal to total number of characters?

Comment: I wont the number of labels "_" equal number of character for example 
"car" is the word that i wrote it in my Test file when program read this word "car" on my  program appear three (underscore) _ _ _.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: thanks for you answer but I have problem with the size() & it give this Exception : 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method size() is undefined for the type String
        at HangGame.initLabelPanel(HangGame.java:78)
 at HangGame.<init>(HangGame.java:29)
 at HangGame.main(HangGame.java:155)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it was not size() it is length() method. I have updated my answer, please look now

Comment: thank you very much now i don't have problem but program does not run any thing & i know that you are tired for solving  my program problems but finally I did not get the result & the program give this Exception :


        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HangGame.initLabelPanel(HangGame.java:77)
 at HangGame.<init>(HangGame.java:29)
 at HangGame.main(HangGame.java:154)

Comment: I have added null check if(myword[i] != null) in the answer and updated my answer please review it now

Comment: now it is  good because there is no error and my program can running but with out any labels i will show you my text file do you think the problem with the content of the text file these are content of my text file : 


keyword= University
username= jhon
password= apple

#Keywords are listed below
keyword1=  Computer
keyword2=  University
keyword3=  Cyprus
keyword4=  International
keyword5=  Information Processing
keyword6=  rawaz
keyword7=  tariq 
keyword8=  hawler
keyword9=  kurdistan 
keyword10= ciu
keyword11= zkry
keyword12= ardalan

Comment: I'm sorry I disturbed you, thank you very much for your help
I Don't know how I can try but I will try to solve

Comment: I hope to you best all the best